# Azure Logic App and Dataverse "Perform changeset request"

Tags: azure-logic-apps, dataverse

I'm trying to use the Dataverse connector "Perform a changeset request" in a "normal" Azure Logic App.

I can see it when I look for it in the designer, but after selecting it, I'm not able to add any action.

I have a different behavior if I try from Power Automate Flow where I'm presented with 3 options.

[image]

VS

[image]

Is this not supported for logic apps? Is there some place I can check what i should/can add via code view (json)?

=====================================================================
UPDATE 1

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an expected behavior in Logic apps, In this particular Connector or action is Different from Power Automate. As both have most of the similarities but are different in some ways.

So, In logic apps, you can only connect to it in first place and then you can use the output of that action which other actions of that connector in next step like below:

[image]

**`Operation:`**

[image]

And this is how this Connector works in Logic apps.

Comment: Are you implying I have to use the output (without anything inside) of the Changeset action in subsequent actions I have?  I'm not understanding how i relate the next action to this change set nor how do I define that the changeset closes.

Comment: Yes, you can only use the output of this action in next actions, that's how it works in Logic Apps

Comment: Understood. But what I don't get is, which output or field and where I use it in the next actions.

Comment: In next preview operations

Comment: I'm not able to understand where I'm supposed to use the change request output in the next action (please check my latest image/update in the original question)

Comment: The output of this action should be used in next action add a new row, delete a row(preview) actions

Comment: But which field? Which header? In my last image, where would I put the output?